# Is there a REST API for TrackAvailability?

Tags: powershell, azure-application-insights

I have a PowerShell script that performs on premise tests for APIs that are only available on premise. The type of tests is not relevant for this question. They pass or fail with an error message.

I wish to use the Application Insights [TrackAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackavailability?view=azure-dotnet)
functionality to report the test results to Azure. This would let me monitor everything from the Azure portal.

The question: can I do the same 
[TrackAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackavailability?view=azure-dotnet) logic with e.g. a REST call from PowerShell, instead of using the .NET API?

Comment: do you consider using the method "TrackAvailability" directly in powershell?

Comment: Could be a workaround, however it is not clear if this works with just using eg nuget

Comment: You can take a look at this [thread](http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/03/27/oneliner-to-send-event-to-application-insights/), it's for trackEvent, you can make some changes for your need.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a HTTP Post with Availability Test results. Easiest way would be to create a console app doing TrackAvailability() call, and capture the fiddler trace to know the post body structure. And you can do it from powershell.

The endpoint specs are documented here, but the above approach would get you started quickly.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/EndpointSpecs

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/03/27/oneliner-to-send-event-to-application-insights/):

I did a test, and works fine:

powershell code:

```
$body = (New-Object PSObject `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty name 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Availability' `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty time $([System.dateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('o')) `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty iKey "your instrumentation key" `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty tags (New-Object PSObject `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'ai.cloud.roleInstance' $env:computername `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'ai.internal.sdkVersion' 'one-line-ps:1.0.0') `
    | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty data (New-Object PSObject `
        | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty baseType 'EventData' `
        | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty baseData (New-Object PSObject `
            | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty ver 2 `
            | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty name 'aaaaaaaa from one line script' `
            | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty properties (New-Object PSObject `
                | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty propName 'propValue')))) `
    | ConvertTo-JSON -depth 5; 

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track' -Method 'POST' -UseBasicParsing -body $body
```

Test result:

[image]

You can also directly use `TrackAvailability` method in the powershell, just copy the "`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll`" to a folder, then use add-type to add it. A simple case as below:

[image]

Comment: Pretty close: when I use the first way (Invoke-WebRequest ...) then a custom event is logged instead of an availability entry. Is there a different base type for trackavailability items?